# Hiding "preparation to install" window programatically

Tags: c#, .net, installation, windows-installer

Can we hide window populated due to following code,

```
IntPtr updatedHandle = new IntPtr();
UInt32 openVal = MsiInteract.MsiOpenPackage("C:\\MSIGet.MSI", out updatedHandle); //get handle for the MSI
```

I have one C# application that read some information from .MSI file for that i used above code. Which work great for me but one window get populated on **MsiOpenPackage** function call.As this function is in loop so it is fustrated for me when multiple window gets open.Please provide me any way to hide "preparation to install" window on function call **MsiOpenPackage** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To suppress the UI shown when opening a package, you need to call [MsiSetInternalUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370389.aspx) or, if you wanted to show something else instead, [MsiSetExternalUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370384.aspx). However if all you're doing is reading information from the [Property table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370908.aspx) or [Summary Information Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370301.aspx), you can just call [MsiOpenDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370338.aspx) instead of [MsiOpenPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370339.aspx) as that will not begin an installation session and thus will not show UI.

Answer (score 0):

Using the quiet installer You can avoid any window opening for user confirmation or dialog.

```
string installer = _installer;
                System.Diagnostics.Process FProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                FProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "MsiExec.exe";
                FProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/quiet /i " + installer;
                FProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                FProcess.Start();
                FProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but dear i am not interested in executing MSIGet.MSI file. I just want to read MSIGet.MSI file to get version and ETC information.